# MDL Javascript conflict with Twitter widget

Tags: javascript, material-design-lite

So, I'm having a problem with MDL's javascript breaking my Twitter widget for showing tweets on the sidebar.

When I remove the javascript, it works perfectly fine. I tried changing the position of the script, but nothing resolves the issue, whenever the MDL's javascript finishes loading, the widget is instantly gone.

If you take a look with "inspect element" you can see the widget's iframe is still there below the facebook widget, but its body is empty.
You can take a look at the issues [right here](http://testtabr.tumblr.com/). Please don't mind the messy code, I will still make a lot of changes and optimizations.

Comment: what's with this error: `Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('http://tonightalive.com.br') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://testtabr.tumblr.com').` ?

Comment: Oh, this is related to a request being made to the original site's url and getting rejected because it's coming from the test environment I created. However, it has no connection to the Twitter widget...